# GeoLocation Google Maps not working

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

I'm trying to get range-rings on my map, with the position of the image above the user's location, but the map doesn't appear when I test it and the user's location doesn't seem to show up on the map. I don't know what went wrong, I followed a tutorial on a website. 
This is the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Radar</title>
 <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="300">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
<style>
 #map-canvas {
  height: 700px;
  }
 #logo {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 99;
  top: 8%;
  left: 3%;
  opacity: 0.9;
 }
 #legenda {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 98;
  top: 87%;
  left: 82%;
   opacity: 1.0;
  height: 50px;
 }
       </style>
    </head>
    <body style="overflow: hidden;">

        <div id="map-canvas"></div>

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
        <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
// [START region_initialization]
// This example creates a custom overlay called USGSOverlay, containing
// a U.S. Geological Survey (USGS) image of the relevant area on the map.

// Set the custom overlay object's prototype to a new instance
// of OverlayView. In effect, this will subclass the overlay class.
// Note that we set the prototype to an instance, rather than the
// parent class itself, because we do not wish to modify the parent class.

var overlay;
USGSOverlay.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();

// Initialize the map and the custom overlay.

function initialize() {

if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success);
} else {
  error('Geo Location is not supported');
}



function success(position) {
     var lat = position.coords.latitude;
     var long = position.coords.longitude;
}

var coords = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
  

var styles =
[ { "featureType": "administrative", "elementType": "geometry.fill", "stylers": [ { "lightness": -88 }, { "saturation": -100 }, { "visibility": "on" } ] },{ "featureType": "administrative.country", "stylers": [ { "visibility": "on" }, { "weight": 1.3 }, { "lightness": 100 } ] },{ "featureType": "landscape", "stylers": [ { "saturation": -100 }, { "lightness": -81 } ] },{ "featureType": "poi", "stylers": [ { "visibility": "off" } ] },{ "featureType": "road.local", "stylers": [ { "visibility": "off" } ] },{ "featureType": "road.arterial", "elementType": "geometry", "stylers": [ { "visibility": "off" } ] },{ "featureType": "road.highway.controlled_access", "stylers": [ { "visibility": "simplified" } ] },{ "featureType": "road.highway.controlled_access", "elementType": "geometry.fill", "stylers": [ { "visibility": "simplified" }, { "saturation": -100 }, { "lightness": 100 }, { "weight": 1.3 } ] },{ "featureType": "road.highway", "stylers": [ { "visibility": "simplified" } ] },{ "featureType": "administrative.locality", "elementType": "labels", "stylers": [ { "lightness": 100 }, { "visibility": "simplified" } ] },{ "featureType": "road.highway", "elementType": "geometry.fill", "stylers": [ { "visibility": "simplified" }, { "lightness": 100 } ] },{ "featureType": "administrative.province", "elementType": "geometry.stroke", "stylers": [ { "lightness": 100 }, { "saturation": -100 } ] },{ "featureType": "administrative.locality", "elementType": "labels.icon", "stylers": [ { "visibility": "off" } ] },{ "featureType": "road", "elementType": "geometry", "stylers": [ { "lightness": -65 }, { "saturation": 1 }, { "hue": "#0000ff" } ] },{ "featureType": "water", "stylers": [ { "saturation": -53 }, { "lightness": -36 }, { "hue": "#00f6ff" } ] },{ "featureType": "landscape", "stylers": [ { "lightness": -39 } ] },{ } ]

  // Create a new StyledMapType object, passing it the array of styles,
  // as well as the name to be displayed on the map type control.
  var styledMap = new google.maps.StyledMapType(styles,
    {name: "Styled Map"});



  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 7,
    center: coords,
 panControl: false,
    zoomControl: false,
 mapTypeControl: false,
 streetViewControl: false,
          mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, 'map_style']


  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);

 map.mapTypes.set('map_style', styledMap);
  map.setMapTypeId('map_style');



var icon = { 
    url: 'met.nl.eu.org/klanten/python/marker.png'
};

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: coords,
      map: map,
      icon: icon
  });



                // Query and plot the data once the map is ready
                google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function() {

                    $.ajax({
                        dataType: "json",
                        url: "http://met.nl.eu.org/klanten/python/get_lightnings.php"
                    }).done(function(data) {

                        data.d.forEach(function(lightning) {
    
    var image = 'http://met.nl.eu.org/klanten/python/strike.png'
                            new google.maps.Marker({
                                position: new google.maps.LatLng(lightning.lat, lightning.lon),
                                map: map,
    icon: image });
  });
 });
 });

var swBound = new google.maps.LatLng(48.895311, 0.000000);
var neBound = new google.maps.LatLng(55.973607, 10.856428);
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(swBound, neBound);

  // The photograph is courtesy of MetNL.
  var srcImage = 'v2.0/historie/28-06-11/00.png';

  // The custom USGSOverlay object contains the USGS image,
  // the bounds of the image, and a reference to the map.
  overlay = new USGSOverlay(bounds, srcImage, map);
}
// [END region_initialization]

// [START region_constructor]
/** @constructor */
function USGSOverlay(bounds, image, map) {

  // Initialize all properties.
  this.bounds_ = bounds;
  this.image_ = image;
  this.map_ = map;

  // Define a property to hold the image's div. We'll
  // actually create this div upon receipt of the onAdd()
  // method so we'll leave it null for now.
  this.div_ = null;

  // Explicitly call setMap on this overlay.
  this.setMap(map);
}
// [END region_constructor]

// [START region_attachment]
/**
 * onAdd is called when the map's panes are ready and the overlay has been
 * added to the map.
 */
USGSOverlay.prototype.onAdd = function() {

  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.style.borderStyle = 'none';
  div.style.borderWidth = '0px';
  div.style.position = 'absolute';

  // Create the img element and attach it to the div.
  var img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src = this.image_;
  img.style.width = '100%';
  img.style.height = '100%';
  img.style.position = 'absolute';
  div.appendChild(img);

  this.div_ = div;

  // Add the element to the "overlayLayer" pane.
  var panes = this.getPanes();
  panes.overlayLayer.appendChild(div);
};
// [END region_attachment]

// [START region_drawing]
USGSOverlay.prototype.draw = function() {

  // We use the south-west and north-east
  // coordinates of the overlay to peg it to the correct position and size.
  // To do this, we need to retrieve the projection from the overlay.
  var overlayProjection = this.getProjection();

  // Retrieve the south-west and north-east coordinates of this overlay
  // in LatLngs and convert them to pixel coordinates.
  // We'll use these coordinates to resize the div.
  var sw = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getSouthWest());
  var ne = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getNorthEast());

  // Resize the image's div to fit the indicated dimensions.
  var div = this.div_;
  div.style.left = sw.x + 'px';
  div.style.top = ne.y + 'px';
  div.style.width = (ne.x - sw.x) + 'px';
  div.style.height = (sw.y - ne.y) + 'px';
};
// [END region_drawing]

// [START region_removal]
// The onRemove() method will be called automatically from the API if
// we ever set the overlay's map property to 'null'.
USGSOverlay.prototype.onRemove = function() {
  this.div_.parentNode.removeChild(this.div_);
  this.div_ = null;
};
// [END region_removal]

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize); 

        </script>
 <img src="http://met.nl.eu.org/NL_nl/iframe/logo.png" id="logo"/>
 <img src="http://met.nl.eu.org/klanten/python/legenda.png" id="legenda"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Wat went wrong with my code?

**Edit: Ik now know the fault occurs in this portion of the code: var coords = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
It gives a reference error saying "position is not defined" while earlier in the code i've written this: function success(position) {
     var lat = position.coords.latitude;
     var long = position.coords.longitude;
}

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: position is not defined`

Comment: What does that mean?

Answer (score 1):

geolocation runs asynchronously.

You may either create the map/marker when it returns a result or define a default-coordinate and update map/marker when it returns a result.

The 2nd approach is preferable, because you wouldn't get a map at all when geolocation fails.

A simple implementation using a MVCObject, which makes it easy to 1. access the value and 2. observe changes(I've removed the irrelevant parts):

```
function initialize() {

    //define a default-position
    var coords = new google.maps.MVCObject();
    coords.set('latlng', new google.maps.LatLng(52.370215, 4.895167));

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success);
    }


    //set new value for coords
    function success(position) {
        coords.set('latlng',
            new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
                position.coords.longitude));
    }

    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 7,
        center: coords.get('latlng')
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
        mapOptions);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: coords.get('latlng'),
        map: map
    });

    //observe the latlng-property of coords,
    //and update marker and map-center when it changes
    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(coords, 'latlng_changed', function () {
        var latlng = this.get('latlng');
        map.setCenter(latlng);
        marker.setPosition(latlng)
    });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Demo: [**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/rttvLsLs/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/rttvLsLs/)

Comment: Thnx. This script works as is, but when i add it to the rest of my script, it suddenly stops and the page goes blank. Is there anything else in my script that might block the geolocation service?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should include your Google Api key.

Try to add the script below :

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap"
type="text/javascript"></script>
```