# Google Maps JS API Geolocation Permission Denied

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm using the Geolocation function to attempt to find the user's device via HTML5 as provided here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation

Everything works great if the user accepts the prompt, but I would like to provide an alternate set of LatLng coordinates if the user denies permission. Currently (including Google's example linked above) if the user denies permission, it renders a blank space where the map should be.

So if the user accepts, render map centered at their location, and if the user denies permission, render map centered at an alternate geopoint.

```js
// Note: This example requires that you consent to location sharing when
// prompted by your browser. If you see a blank space instead of the map, this
// is probably because you have denied permission for location sharing.

var map;

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 6
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);

  // Try HTML5 geolocation
  if(navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
                                       position.coords.longitude);

      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        map: map,
        position: pos,
        content: 'Location found using HTML5.'
      });

      map.setCenter(pos);
    }, function() {
      handleNoGeolocation(true);
    });
  } else {
    // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
    handleNoGeolocation(false);
  }
}

function handleNoGeolocation(errorFlag) {
  if (errorFlag) {
    var content = 'Error: The Geolocation service failed.';
  } else {
    var content = 'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.';
  }

  var options = {
    map: map,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(60, 105),
    content: content
  };

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(options);
  map.setCenter(options.position);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: You are using the general HTML5 Geolocation API, not a "Google Maps JS API"

Comment: I don't understand. The page I am using is found under: **Google Maps JavaScript API v3**:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation

Is there a different geolocation service I should be using?

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/29831923/459897

Comment: That's perfect, thanks!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29829470/geolocation-google-maps-not-working/29831923#29831923

Comment: This previous post fixed my issue:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29829470/geolocation-google-maps-not-working/29831923#29831923